# Extract Alerts logs from Azure without Azure security Centre

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-security, devops-services

[image: Log-analytics showing no related to alerts][image: Screenshot of Alerts]I want to extract alerts log in **CSV** format to show that I have received this type of alerts.
But unable to extract from **azure log query** Or I have to install some **agent**?

Comment: can you please attach some screenshots? It's better for others to do the troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, Sure
I want this all alert of 30 days in form of logs or in CSV  format.
It will also okay with azure query language for alert

Comment: My test shows that querying the Alert table will only give you alerts that are based on Alert Rules that you have created yourself. Alerts automatically generated by Azure wont show up.

Comment: @RiteshJhaggar, do you mind using the [Alerts - Get All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall) rest api? but it returns json format, you need to convert to .csv by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may list all existing alerts, where the results can be filtered on the basis of multiple parameters (e.g. time range). The results can then be sorted on the basis specific fields, with the default being lastModifiedDateTime:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts?api-version=2018-05-05
```

Similar with Optional Parameters:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts?targetResource={targetResource}&targetResourceType={targetResourceType}&targetResourceGroup={targetResourceGroup}&monitorService={monitorService}&monitorCondition={monitorCondition}&severity={severity}&alertState={alertState}&alertRule={alertRule}&smartGroupId={smartGroupId}&includeContext={includeContext}&includeEgressConfig={includeEgressConfig}&pageCount={pageCount}&sortBy={sortBy}&sortOrder={sortOrder}&select={select}&timeRange={timeRange}&customTimeRange={customTimeRange}&api-version=2018-05-05
```

To check other URI parameter for Logging, you may refer this [**URL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall).

And finally when you have availed response(s) in JSON format, you may get that automatically converted into CSV format using any of the *freely* available online conversion utilities (like this service [**HERE**](https://json-csv.com/))